# Wordpress Error: Database Update Required

Tags: database, wordpress, plugins

I'm currently working with a client right now that clicked to update a plugin on WordPress. He's unaware of what plugin it was that he updated because he's clicked update in the past for other plugins and they just updated, so he paid little attention to what it was he clicked.

His site is still up, but when I try to get into the back end using /wp-admin I'm hit with a message that states:

> *Database Update Required*
>
> *WordPress has been updated! Before we send you on your way, we have to update your database to the newest version.*
>
> *The update process may take a little while, so please be patient.*
>
> *Update Wordpress Database*

When I click on the button that says "Update WordPress Database" it does nothing. The browser spins and then shows me a blank white page with Wordpress at the top. I'm at a loss because I can't even login, it doesn't give me the option.

Any thoughts on what is happening? Thanks a bunch in advance for the assistance.

Comment: You might want to check out http://wordpress.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 60):

This is due to a missmatch between the databases versions you said you are using in the settings.

Please follow this steps:

1. Go to `/wp-include/` folder and open the `version.php`.
2. Find the value for  `$wp_db_version`, and write it down.
3. Now, open your database, check in the table called `wp_options`
4. Find the `db_version` value:

   `SELECT option_value FROM yourdatabase.wp_options WHERE option_name = 'db_version';`
5. Those two values **must be the same**. Change it in the `version.php` file, not the database.

---

Source: http://wpquestions.com/question/showChrono/id/4151

Comment: Thanks for this - definitely the issue I had and was due to the version.php not having write permissions

Comment: this saved me. Thank you

Comment: I had to restore files from backup after a client's plugin upgrade failed, and then this occurred.  Likely due to not also restoring db from same timeframe, but this solution fixed it.

Answer (score 2):

Restarting php-fpm service helped me, it clears cache on restart

```
sudo service php5-fpm restart
```

Hope that helps some folks out there.

Comment: That did the trick for me with `wordpress 5.8.1` and `sudo service php7.4-fpm restart`

Answer (score -1):

1. Try clearing your browser cache
2. The option db_upgraded isn’t getting set by the upgrade process.
   Try this: go to `/wp-admin/options.php`. Fill the field `db_upgraded` with a `0` (zero). Hit *Save Changes*.

Comment: there is no `db_upgraded`, do you mean `db_version``?

Answer (score -4):

This is due to a missmatch between the databases versions you said you are using in the settings.

Please follow this steps:

1. Go to `/wp-include/` folder and open the `version.php`.
2. Find the value for  `$wp_db_version`, and write it down.
3. Open your database, check in the table called `wp_options`
4. Find the db_version value:

   ```
   SELECT option_value FROM yourdatabase.wp_options WHERE option_name = 'db_version';
   ```

Those two values must be the same. Change it in the `version.php` file, not the database.