# "Database Update Required" wordpress caused login issue

Tags: database

We updated Wordpress admin panel to 4.0 and following that, was directed to a window that said:

*Database Update Required
*WordPress has been updated! Before we send you on your way, we have to update your database to the newest version.The update process may take a little while, so please be patient.**

We clicked on "Update database", it took us to a window that said:

*'Update Complete
Your WordPress database has been successfully updated!'*

We clicked continue, and it sent us back to "Database update required" window, we've been going around in a LOOP like this without access to the admin panel...

Then we found the answer to the problem here 
[Wordpress Error: Database Update Required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17308436/wordpress-error-database-update-required)

So we did that:

```
Go to /wp-include/ folder and open the version.php.
Find the value for $wp_db_version, and write it down.
Now, open your database, check in the table called wp_options

Find the db_version value:

SELECT option_value FROM yourdatabase.wp_options WHERE option_name = 'db_version';

Those two values must be the same. Change it in the version.php file, not the database.
```

We fixed a part of the problem, because now we don't have the 'database update' window showing up anymore, we see the normal login page.

But we can't login! It's impossible. It doesn't react at all, it just refreshes again and again and again...and we never get in the admin panel.

Can someone help us? We're not professional web developers, we're just 2 girls with a webzine trying to resolve this issue. ( so please don't talk to us like we know the A to Z of coding!)

Ps: We have some plugins which we did not disable during the updating process. Also, a few days before this all happened, we downloaded some plugins that didn't work out, but we removed them.

Comment: This site is a Q&A site for programming questions. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ might be a better site.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Wordpress Error: Database Update Required](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17308436/wordpress-error-database-update-required)