# Wordpress: There has been an error with the API: PUBLISHING_NOT_ALLOWED

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm experiencing an strange error with Wordpress after performing an upgrade that failed and then semi-fixed it.

Specifically, when I try to publish a new post or edit an old post, I get an error:

`There has been an error with the API: PUBLISHING_NOT_ALLOWED`

The odd thing though is that the post still publishes just fine, and still saves when editing.

Long story: the upgrade to Wordpress 4.7 failed. I used this [force_upgrade.php](https://gist.github.com/collegeman/1120221) script to attempt a fix (has worked great for me in the past), and eventually [resorted to this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17308436/wordpress-error-database-update-required/23506630#23506630) (changing $wp_db_version in version.php in /wp-includes/), after a [manual update](https://codex.wordpress.org/Updating_WordPress) to 4.7 didn't work.

Any suggests to fixing the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PUBLISHING_NOT_ALLOWED is one possible error message from the [Apple News API](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/News_API_Ref/CreateArticle.html). It's returned when a "channel" isn't allowed to publish content.

You should disable whatever plugin is publishing to Apple News or contact Apple to get your site approved for publishing.